# Исчезают элементы формы при добавлении JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Никак не могу понять - при добавлении ( а точнее даже при объявлении, без инициализации ) элемента JTextField пропадают элементы формы

Код Main класса

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Calculator");

        window.setSize(280, 347);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // установка по центру экрана
        window.setResizable(false); // запрет изменять размеры окна
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

        window.add(new Panel());

    }
}
```

Код панели

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel {



//шрифт
private Font font = new Font("SanSerif",Font.BOLD, 20);

private final int buttonSize = 50;
private final int spaceSize = 10;

//private JTextField output = new JTextField(); ЕСЛИ РАССКОМЕНТИТЬ - кнока 0 исчезнет


    public Panel() {

        // позволяет размещать элементы в любом месте формы
        setLayout(null);

        //генерация кнопки 0
        JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
        zeroButton.setFont(font);
        zeroButton.setBounds(70,250,buttonSize,buttonSize);
        add(zeroButton);

        //output

/*
        output.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
        output.setEnabled(false); // forbid to change
        add(output);
        */
    }
}
```

Если расскоменитить код с JTextField то кнопка 0 пропадает ( а также другие кнопки если их разместить)

[image: Было]
[image: Стало]

Comment: у меня и без расскоментирования ничего на форме не выводится

Comment: Хз, у меня выводится - картинку с кнопкой 0 прикреплял